# Add Google Calender in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to add google calender in my React Js App but not been able to integrate, im very much close i have no idea where is error in given code. When i click add event it takes google sign in and then no response it suppose to be open in new link along with google Calender.Please do help if u have any idea about Thanks

```
import React from 'react';



function GoogleCalender() {

var gapi = window.gapi
 /* 
 Update with your own Client Id and Api key 
 */
  var CLIENT_ID = ""
 var API_KEY = ""
 var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"]
var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events"

const handleClick = () => {
gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
  console.log('loaded client')

  gapi.client.init({
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
    scope: SCOPES,
  })

  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', () => console.log('bam!'))

  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()
  .then(() => {
    
    var event = {
      'summary': 'Awesome Event!',
      'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
      'description': 'Really great refreshments',
      'start': {
        'dateTime': '2020-06-28T09:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
      },
      'end': {
        'dateTime': '2020-06-28T17:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
      },
      'recurrence': [
        'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
      ],
      'attendees': [
        {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
        {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'}
      ],
      'reminders': {
        'useDefault': false,
        'overrides': [
          {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
          {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}
        ]
      }
    }

    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
      'calendarId': 'primary',
      'resource': event,
    })

    request.execute(event => {
      console.log(event)
      window.open(event.htmlLink)
    })
    

   

   })
   })
 }


return (
<div className="App">
  <header className="App-header">
    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
    <p>Click to add event to Google Calendar</p>
    <p style={{fontSize: 18}}>Uncomment the get events code to get events</p>
    <p style={{fontSize: 18}}>Don't forget to add your Client Id and Api key</p>
    <button style={{width: 100, height: 50}} onClick={handleClick}>Add Event</button>
  </header>
</div>
);
}

export default GoogleCalender;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i got the solution from https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js

```js
import React from "react"
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react" // must go before plugins
import "./GoogleCalender.css"
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid" // a plugin!
import { gapi } from "gapi-script"

/* global gapi */
const GoogleCalender = () => {
  const CLIENT_ID = "615021829008-escfim5jvcvlnudmu866.googleusercontent.com"
  const API_KEY = ""

  // Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
  const DISCOVERY_DOC =
    "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"

  // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
  // included, separated by spaces.
  const SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"

  let tokenClient
  let gapiInited = false
  let gisInited = false
  // var gapi=window.gapi;
  const google = window.google

  function gapiLoaded() {
    gapi.load("client", initializeGapiClient)
  }

  /**
   * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
   * discovery doc to initialize the API.
   */
  async function initializeGapiClient() {
    await gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: API_KEY,
      discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
    })
    gapiInited = true
    maybeEnableButtons()
  }

  function gisLoaded() {
    tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES,
      callback: "", // defined later
    })
    gisInited = true
    maybeEnableButtons()
  }

  /**
   * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
   */
  function maybeEnableButtons() {
    if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
    }
  }

  function handleAuthClick() {
    tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
      if (resp.error !== undefined) {
        throw resp
      }
      document.getElementById("signout_button").style.visibility = "visible"
      document.getElementById("authorize_button").innerText = "Refresh"
      await listUpcomingEvents()
    }

    if (gapi?.client?.getToken() === null) {
      // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
      // when establishing a new session.
      tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: "consent" })
    } else {
      // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
      tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: "" })
    }
  }
  function handleSignoutClick() {
    const token = gapi?.client?.getToken()
    if (token !== null) {
      google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token?.access_token)
      gapi?.client?.setToken("")

      // document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
      // document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  }

  async function listUpcomingEvents() {
    let response
    try {
      const request = {
        calendarId: "primary",
        timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
        showDeleted: false,
        singleEvents: true,
        maxResults: 10,
        orderBy: "startTime",
      }
      response = await gapi.client.calendar.events.list(request)

      var event = {
        summary: "Awesome Event!",
        location: "800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103",
        description: "Really great refreshments",
        start: {
          dateTime: "2020-06-28T09:00:00-07:00",
          timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles",
        },
        end: {
          dateTime: "2020-06-28T17:00:00-07:00",
          timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles",
        },
        recurrence: ["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"],
        attendees: [
          { email: "lpage@example.com" },
          { email: "sbrin@example.com" },
        ],
        reminders: {
          useDefault: false,
          overrides: [
            { method: "email", minutes: 24 * 60 },
            { method: "popup", minutes: 10 },
          ],
        },
      }

      var request1 = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
        calendarId: "primary",
        resource: event,
      })

      request1.execute((event) => {
        console.log(event)
        window.open(event.htmlLink)
      })
    } catch (err) {
      document.getElementById("content").innerText = err.message
      return
    }

    const events = response.result.items
    if (!events || events.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("content").innerText = "No events found."
      return
    }
    // Flatten to string to display
    const output = events.reduce(
      (str, event) =>
        `${str}${event.summary} (${
          event.start.dateTime || event.start.date
        })\n`,
      "Events:\n"
    )
    document.getElementById("content").innerText = output
  }
  gisLoaded()
  gapiLoaded()

  return (
    <>
      <div className="mainContainerGoogleCal">
        <button id="authorize_button" onClick={handleAuthClick}>
          Authorize
        </button>
        <button id="signout_button" onClick={handleSignoutClick}>
          Sign Out
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default GoogleCalender
```